# gcloud functions deploy go runtime error "undefined: unsafe.Slice; Error ID: 2f5e35a0"

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, slice, gcloud, google-cloud-build

While deploying to google cloud function, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: # projectname/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix
src/projectname/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall.go:83:16: undefined: unsafe.Slice
src/projectname/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_linux.go:2255:9: undefined: unsafe.Slice
src/projectname/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_unix.go:118:7: undefined: unsafe.Slice
src/projectname/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/sysvshm_unix.go:33:7: undefined: unsafe.Slice; Error ID: 2f5e35a0
```

Here's my command:

```
gcloud functions deploy servicename --region=us-central1 --entry-point=gofunctionname --runtime=go116 --source=.
```

I am using vendoring to package my dependencies. It's been a while I have updated this function. And first time I noticed this error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [`unsafe.Slice`](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe@go1.17#Slice) was added in Go 1.17 and Cloud Functions (frustratingly) hasn't evolved beyond Go 1.16. `unsafe.Slice` is returned by [syscall.go:83.16](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/sys/+/master:unix/syscall.go;l=83) so, I suspect you've bumped that package or another that uses it and you'll need to either revert or determine what introduced it.

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin. It was a compatibility issue i guess. I reverted back the reference to `golang.org/x/sys` and it fixed the deployment issue for me.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As DazWilkin suggested above, `unsafe.Slice` was added as part of Go 1.17 and GCP Functions support Go 1.16 as of now.

I had to revert back the `golang.org/x/sys` module in the `go.mod` file and it worked for me.

From

```
golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20221010170243-090e33056c14 // indirect
```

To

```
golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20220811171246-fbc7d0a398ab // indirect
```

With this change, I am able to build and deploy the code to Google Cloud Functions.

Comment: run this command at your project root should be easier. `go mod edit -go='1.16' -replace='golang.org/x/sys'='golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20220811171246-fbc7d0a398ab'`

Answer (score 2):

As of the time of writing this, Google Cloud Functions now supports [Go 1.18 and Go 1.19](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment).

Update your project to `go119` and you shouldn't have this issue anymore. For example:

```
gcloud functions deploy servicename --runtime=go119 --region=us-central1
```